# Jersey hides Spring framework and SockJS

Tags: java, spring, websocket, jersey, sockjs

We're trying to expose sockjs endpoints with [Spring Framework WebSocket support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html).

This is the configuration on the server side where Jersey is managing the routes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/sockjs").withSockJS()
                .setStreamBytesLimit(512 * 1024)
                .setHttpMessageCacheSize(1000)
                .setDisconnectDelay(30 * 1000);
    }
}
```

The problem is that we can't access `/sockjs`, the client code is:

```
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(2);
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());

SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
sockJsClient.doHandshake(new MyHandler(), "ws://localhost:8080/sockjs");
```

(the code is from spring [websockets tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-intro))

Other resources in the same package would've configured under `root/api/server`, even though, not `/sockjs` nor `/root/api/server/sockjs` are accessible.

Comment: What's you're URL mapping for Jersey?

Comment: In the `web.xml` we configured this:
`<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name><url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>`

We also have `/root` prefix as part of the tomcat webapp configuration
A resource above the same package defines the `/server` path

Comment: So it works if you disable Jersey?

Comment: No, and it led us to understand that spring-web didn't initialized correctly in order to register this endpoints. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Noam could you please share solution which helped you? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry it was long time ago, did you initialize everything correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite ancient question, but lately I've bumped into the same problem and I've spent half a day to find a solution. As I've found one I'd like to share it, at least for future myself.

The problem was that I had only Jersey's servlet definition inside my `WEB-INF.xml`. The solution was to add Spring's `DispatcherServlet` and its mapping to the `/*` route.

So basically it looks like

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```